# QGIS Grid rasters have no resolution setting

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, interpolation

In earlier versions of QGIS you could create rasters like heat map and interpolation, and define the resolution of the raster.

In 3.10 I see these dialogs are new, and raster size fields disappeared. So no matter what settings I use, the resulting raster is about 280 px in the biggest dimension.

How do I change the resolution?

[image]

[image]